# ERROR: java.lang.numberformatexception in tp calculator app

Tags: android-studio

My Java Program is:

```
package slidingmenu.androidhive.info.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText amt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bill_amt);
        final EditText tip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bill_per);
        final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);

        Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.toString());
                double tip_per = Double.parseDouble(tip.toString());
                double tip_cal = (amount / tip_per);
                result.setText("Result : " + Double.toString(tip_cal));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and my logcat is :

```
 04-12 19:27:24.372 1203-     1203/slidingmenu.androidhive.info.myapplication 
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "android.widget.EditText{5320176c VFED..CL ........ 32,257-736,336 #7f0c006d app:id/bill_amt}"
```

How can I resolve this error..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Making a guess, but you may not implementing the correct method on the right object. Maybe since, amt variable is of type TextEdit, try changing it to this:

```
Double.parseDouble(amt.getText().toString());
Double.parseDouble(tip.getText().toString());
```

Let me know if this helps.